# How to recover information stored in .ctors section?

Tags: disassembly, x86, c++, elf

Test is on x86, 32-bit Linux. I am using `g++` 4.6.3 and `objdump` 2.22

Here is a simple C++ code I am working on:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it into assembly code using :

```
gcc -S hello.cc
```

I can find out a `ctors` section in the **hello.s** below:

```
.section    .ctors,"aw",@progbits
.align 4
.long   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
.weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_oncePiPFvvE,pthread_once
.weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_getspecificj,pthread_getspecific
.weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_setspecificjPKv,pthread_setspecific
.weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_createPmPK14pthread_attr_tPFPvS3_ES3_,pthread_create
.weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_joinmPPv,pthread_join
.weakref    _ZL21__gthrw_pthread_equalmm,pthread_equal
.weakref    _ZL20__gthrw_pthread_selfv,pthread_self
.weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_detachm,pthread_detach
.weakref    _ZL22__gthrw_pthread_cancelm,pthread_cancel
.weakref    _ZL19__gthrw_sched_yieldv,sched_yield
.weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_lockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_lock
.weakref    _ZL29__gthrw_pthread_mutex_trylockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_trylock
.weakref    _ZL31__gthrw_pthread_mutex_timedlockP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec,pthread_mutex_timedlock
.weakref    _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_mutex_unlockP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_unlock
.weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_mutex_initP15pthread_mutex_tPK19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutex_init
.weakref    _ZL29__gthrw_pthread_mutex_destroyP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_mutex_destroy
.weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_cond_broadcastP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_broadcast
.weakref    _ZL27__gthrw_pthread_cond_signalP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_signal
.weakref    _ZL25__gthrw_pthread_cond_waitP14pthread_cond_tP15pthread_mutex_t,pthread_cond_wait
.weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_cond_timedwaitP14pthread_cond_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec,pthread_cond_timedwait
.weakref    _ZL28__gthrw_pthread_cond_destroyP14pthread_cond_t,pthread_cond_destroy
.weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE,pthread_key_create
.weakref    _ZL26__gthrw_pthread_key_deletej,pthread_key_delete
.weakref    _ZL30__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_initP19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutexattr_init
.weakref    _ZL33__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_settypeP19pthread_mutexattr_ti,pthread_mutexattr_settype
.weakref    _ZL33__gthrw_pthread_mutexattr_destroyP19pthread_mutexattr_t,pthread_mutexattr_destroy
```

However, when I assembly the asm code, producing an exe file and use the `objdump` produce the `ctors` section's contain like this:

```
objdump -Dr -j .ctors hellocpp
```

All I can get is like this:

```
hellocpp:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .ctors:

08049efc <__CTOR_LIST__>:
 8049efc:   ff                      (bad)  
 8049efd:   ff                      (bad)  
 8049efe:   ff                      (bad)  
 8049eff:   ff 00                   incl   (%eax)

08049f00 <__CTOR_END__>:
 8049f00:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
 ...
```

Currently I am trying to recover the content of some ELF binaries compiled from `c++` program..

So I am wondering if there is a way to get the content of `ctors` which equals to what `g++` produced?

#### Update:

Thanks a lot for @Igor's help. But I am still trapped in looking for `class's` `constructor` and `destructor`  info from ELF binary.

When evolving `class` definition, g++ would produce these info in the `.ctors` section:

```
    .globl  _ZN8ComputerC1Ev
    .set    _ZN8ComputerC1Ev,_ZN8ComputerC2Ev
    .globl  _ZN8ComputerD1Ev
    .set    _ZN8ComputerD1Ev,_ZN8ComputerD2Ev
```

Generally `_ZN8ComputerC2Ev` is the name of a class's constructor while `_ZN8ComputerD2Ev` is its  destructor.

However, I just can not find corresponding info in the `objdump` dumped `.ctors` or `.init_array` sections.. I also tried `.eh_frame` and `gcc_except_table`, but the information dumped is massive.. I can not figure out the meaning of those information..

Could anyone give me guide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.ctors` section is a list of pointers terminated with -1 (0xFFFFFFFF), so it does not make sense to disassemble it. If you rearrange the bytes as data, you get:

```
__CTOR_LIST__: .long 0xffffffff
__CTOR_END__:  .long 0x00000000
```

So, for whatever reason, the resulting exe does not actually use the `.ctors` section. I suspect the linker instead placed the pointers into the new-style `.init_array` section. Note that it is, again, a list of pointers, and not code.

**Edit**:

The `.ctors` or `.init_array` sections only contain so-called *constructor functions* - functions that need to be executed at startup, before the `main()` itself. These are usually compiler-generated functions that perform construction of global objects (such as `cin`, `cout` etc.), or other startup-related tasks. You can, in fact, add your own functions to that list using [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work).

What does **not** go there are general C++ class constructors - there is no need to execute those on startup. They will be called when and if you construct an object of a specific class - e.g. by declaring a variable or calling `operator new`.

Comment: Groovy! I dump the content of `.init_array` section and it contains the address of `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main` function!

Answer (score 5):

As Igor stated, the `.ctors` section is a list of function pointers, ending with a sentinel value of `0xffffffff`. To see its contents, just do

```
$ objdump -s -j.ctors bar.so
```

But your assembly file only contains weak symbols. Those are foreign functions in other libraries, and are invoked when their libraries are loaded at runtime.

For example, put this in a file `bar.cpp`:

```
class Foo {
public:
  int i;

  Foo(int n) : i(n) {
  }
};

Foo global_foo(123);
```

Compile with

```
$ g++ -shared -fPIC bar.cpp -obar.so
```

The contents of the `.init_array` section is

```
$ objdump -s -j.init_array bar.so

bar.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .init_array:
 200820 ad060000 00000000                    ........
```

There's a function pointer there, `0xad060000 00000000`. But you have to change its endianness, e.g. with Python:

```
>>> import struct
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack("<Q", 0xad06000000000000))
'00000000000006ad'
```

Now list all symbols and grep for that address:

```
$ objdump -C --syms bar.so | grep 00000000000006ad
00000000000006ad l     F .text  0000000000000015
  [... on above line ...] global constructors keyed to bar.cpp
```

The disassembly for it,

```
$ objdump -C -d bar.so
```

shows

```
00000000000006ad <global constructors keyed to bar.cpp>:
 6ad:   55                      push   %rbp
 6ae:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6b1:   be ff ff 00 00          mov    $0xffff,%esi
 6b6:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 6bb:   e8 ba ff ff ff          callq  67a <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)>
 6c0:   c9                      leaveq 
 6c1:   c3                      retq
```

which jumps to `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)`:

```
000000000000067a <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)>:
 67a:   55                      push   %rbp
 67b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 67e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 682:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
 685:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
 688:   83 7d fc 01             cmpl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
 68c:   75 1d                   jne    6ab <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+0x31>
 68e:   81 7d f8 ff ff 00 00    cmpl   $0xffff,-0x8(%rbp)
 695:   75 14                   jne    6ab <__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)+0x31>
 697:   be 7b 00 00 00          mov    $0x7b,%esi
 69c:   48 8b 05 9d 03 20 00    mov    0x20039d(%rip),%rax        # 200a40 <_DYNAMIC+0x1e8>
 6a3:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 6a6:   e8 f5 fe ff ff          callq  5a0 <Foo::Foo(int)@plt>
 6ab:   c9                      leaveq 
 6ac:   c3                      retq
```

which puts 123 (`0x7b`) on the stack and calls `Foo::Foo(int)`.