# Find function in a stripped dynamic ELF library

Tags: android, arm, elf, java, symbols

Im currently reverse engineering an android app and this app calls a function named "getUserInfo" in an **ARM 32bit ELF library** called ["libcms.so"](https://download1494.mediafire.com/3p93kb4d39mg/6uutljplmxnsxvn/libcms.so) (from TikTok) via the [Java Native Interface](https://www.baeldung.com/jni).

My Problem is: The function cant be found with `readelf --syms libcms.so` or `readelf --dyn-syms libcms.so` because libcms.so is stripped and the funtion is not contained in the symbol table.

The app can call this function, so i know the function is there. How can i find the hex location of the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There're two broad ways in which you can declare `JNI` functions.

The first is the more obvious way in which the `JNI` function has to follow a specific naming convention like `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app_foo_bar`. You can easily identify such functions using `readelf`.

The other not so obvious way is to use `RegisterNatives`. Here your functions can have any signature and further they not need be exported from the shared library. Typically, you would call `RegisterNatives` from `JNI_OnLoad` to register the native functions to the Java Run-time.

For your binary `libcms.so`, it uses the second method.

`RegisterNatives` has the following prototype

```
jint RegisterNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, const JNINativeMethod *methods, jint Methods);
```

If you analyze the code of `JNI_OnLoad` you will come across `RegisterNatives` call like below.

[image]

The third argument points to an array of `JNINativeMethod` structures which is declared as

```
typedef struct {
    char *name; 
    char *signature;
    void *fnPtr;
} JNINativeMethod;
```

The first member is a pointer to a null terminated string denoting the function name. However, in your case all the names and signatures are encrypted.

[image]
[image]

These are decrypted at run-time by the `.datadiv_decodeXXXXXXXX` family of functions. The `.init_array` section contain pointers to these decryptor functions which implies they will be called at startup.

[image]

However, that is not all. The binary also employs [Control Flow Flattening](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/what-is-a-control-flow-flattening-obfuscation-technique) Obfuscation throughout, hence the execution path may not be easily discernible as shown below.

[image]

To analyze the binary you're better off resorting to dynamic analysis techniques using a tool such as [Frida](https://www.frida.re/).

**Further Read:**

- https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#native-libraries
- [Finding RegisterNatives function calls in JNI_OnLoad's assembly code](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19024/finding-registernatives-function-calls-in-jni-onloads-assembly-code)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509961/which-method-eventually-calls-jni-onload
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811348/find-manually-registered-obfuscated-native-function-address
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010645/what-does-the-registernatives-method-do
- [How to recover information stored in .ctors section?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/how-to-recover-information-stored-in-ctors-section)

Comment: I don't understand, can dynamically load it get the function or anyway? or am I missing the point?

Comment: @GinMay To decrypt the function names you can run/emulate the `.datadiv_decode` series of functions.